# Is there any way to get model object instead of stdClass object while using Laravel DB:Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

In below code i tried  to get nearby users and distances. Everything is working well. But below query returns results as a **stdClass Object** But I want User **Model Object**. Is it possible?

```
   $collection =  DB::table('users')
        ->join('locations as l', 'users.location_id', '=', 'l.id')
        ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) as distances'))
        ->having('distances', '<', 32.688888)
        ->orderBy('distances', 'ASC')
        ->get();
```

**Output:**

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (

                    )
             )
    )
```

**I want**

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => App\Models\User Object
                    (

                    )
             )
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using the query builder instead of the model.

You should be able to achieve what you're after with the following:

```
$collection =  User::join('locations as l', 'users.location_id', '=', 'l.id')
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('(6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * cos(radians(`lat`)) * cos(radians(`lng`) - radians(' . $coordinates['longitude'] . ')) + sin(radians(' . $coordinates['latitude'] . ')) * sin(radians(`lat`)))) as distances'))
    ->having('distances', '<', 32.688888)
    ->orderBy('distances', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: @weaver This part can be confusing at first. `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` will forward calls by `__call` to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, which in turn will forward calls to `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`. This is why you can treat the two latter classes as a part of your model class, and call them directly from the model when building complex queries. This also goes for static calls, like with User::join, which will instantiate a new object and after that call the object's non-static methods. See `__callStatic`.

Comment: The title of the question clearly states how to do it **using query builder**. If it is impossible, please add additional information stating that and then your answer, as right now, you are not answering the question asked in the title.

Comment: @Silidrone That’s what I was trying to achieve with my opening sentence.